# Why can my Go Iris app not be deployed to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, go, govendor, go-iris

I have very simple Go App with Iris which I am trying to deploy to Heroku.

To build and install locally I run the following command:

```
go install -v -tags heroku .
```

This works and outputs

```
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/BurntSushi/toml
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/fatih/structs
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/cfg
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/ruleset
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/pio/terminal
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/form-binder
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/satori/go.uuid
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/cpuid
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/crc32
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/pio
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/atom
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/errors
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/net/html
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/entry
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/compress/flate
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/golog
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/uri
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/acme
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/ast
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/token
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/lexer
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/parser
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/field
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/persistence
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/ryanuber/columnize
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/Joker/jade
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/compress/gzip
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/ast
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/lexer
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/eknkc/amber/parser
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/juju/errors
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/memstore
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/parser
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/gopkg.in/yaml.v2
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/flosch/pongo2
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/netutil
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/host
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/eknkc/amber
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/context
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/client/rule
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/handlerconv
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/methodfunc
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/node
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/model
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/sessions
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/client
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/view
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris
github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper
```

This application will run locally without issue. However when I deploy to Heroku using:

```
git push heroku master
```

The following is the output:

```
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Checking vendor/vendor.json file.
remote: -----> Using go1.8.3
remote: -----> Fetching any unsaved dependencies (govendor sync)
remote: -----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku . 
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/BurntSushi/toml
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/pio/terminal
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/pio
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/golog
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/cfg
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/ruleset
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/fatih/structs
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/form-binder
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/satori/go.uuid
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/errors
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/memstore
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/cpuid
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/compress/flate
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/crc32
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/klauspost/compress/gzip
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/atom
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/net/html
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/entry
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/context
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/uri
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/acme
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/client/rule
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache/client
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/handlerconv
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/netutil
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/cache
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/ast
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/token
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/lexer
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro/interpreter/parser
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/host
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/macro
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/node
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/field
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/methodfunc
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/model
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator/persistence
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/ryanuber/columnize
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/mvc/activator
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/Joker/jade
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/ast
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/lexer
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond/parser
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/eknkc/amber/parser
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/aymerick/raymond
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/eknkc/amber
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/juju/errors
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/gopkg.in/yaml.v2
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/flosch/pongo2
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris/view
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/vendor/github.com/kataras/iris
remote: github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper
remote: # github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper
remote: ./main.go:19: undefined: iris.Context
remote: ./main.go:28: undefined: iris.Context
```

I am using govendor and all of the files required are located within the vendor directory of my app. I added them using:

```
govendor add github.com/kataras/iris
govendor add +external
```

What is the issue? Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Look at this line https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/master/context.go#L1 and compare that to heroku's `remote: -----> Using go1.8.3` log output.

Comment: Try updating this line https://github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/blob/master/vendor/vendor.json#L4 to "1.9"

Comment: I cannot use go 1.9 on heroku.

Comment: @mkopriva Should I use an older version of Iris. How?

Comment: Seems like only that one file is intended for `1.9` so you should be fine if you import and use those types that that one file "redefines". That is, instead of using [iris.Context](https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/80b31256608a416ab4968ae7717efe35d8096c79/context.go#L27) in your main.go file import `github.com/kataras/iris/context` and edit [this line](https://github.com/VaccinalBowl/herokulunchhelper/blob/master/main.go#L87) to use `context.Context`. And if you use anything else from the `github.com/kataras/iris/context.go` file you'll need to make similar changes.